# How do I create a directory in Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io

I am new to Perl and trying to write text files.  I can write text files to an existing directory no problem, but ultimately I would like to be able to create my own directories.

I am going to download files from my course works website and I want to put the files in a folder named after the course.  I don't want to make a folder for each course manually beforehand, and I would also like to eventually share the script with others, so I need a way to make the directories and name them based on the course names from the HTML.

So far, I have been able to get this to work:

```
use strict;
my $content = "Hello world";
open MYFILE, ">C:/PerlFiles/test.txt";
print MYFILE $content;
close (MYFILE);
```

`test.txt` doesn't exist, but `C:/PerlFiles/` does and supposedly typing `>` allows me to create files, great.

The following, however does not work:

```
use strict;
my $content = "area = pi*r^2";
open MYFILE, ">C:/PerlFiles/math_class/circle.txt";
print MYFILE $content;
close (MYFILE);
```

The directory `C:/PerlFiles/math_class/` does not exist.

I also tried `sysopen` but I get an error when adding the flags:

```
use strict;
my $content = "area = pi*r^2";
sysopen (MYFILE, ">C:/PerlFiles/math_class/circle.txt", O_CREAT);
print MYFILE $content;
close (MYFILE);
```

I got this idea from the [Perl Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003135/) chapter *7.1. Opening a File*. It doesn't work, and I get the error message `Bareword "O_CREAT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use`.  Then again the book is from 1998, so perhaps `O_CREAT` is obsolete. At some point I think I will need to fork over the dough for an up-to-date version.

But still, what am I missing here?  Or do the directories have to be created manually before creating a file in it?

Comment: `O_CREAT` is not obsolete, it is a symbol provided by the [Fcntl](http://p3rl.org/Fcntl) module. You need to import it thus: `use Fcntl qw(O_CREAT);` – Add that line near your other `use`-statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [File::Path](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/File-Path-2.08/Path.pm) to create arbitrarily deep paths. Use [dirname](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0/lib/File/Basename.pm) to find out a file's containing directory.

Also, use lexical file handles and three-argument open:

```
open(my $fd, ">", $name) or die "Can't open $name: $!";
```

Comment: thanks.  I didnt know about the 3 argument open but it will come in handy when I eventually get to giving them variable names, and variable file handles will no doubt help too.  I haven't really gotten past the basics testing yet.

Comment: @msikd65: They're commonly called *lexical* file handles. A nice feature indeed.

Comment: There's a set of standard `File::*` modules that are installed with Perl.  See `perldoc perlmodlib` for a complete list.

Answer (score 8):

Right, directories have to be created manually.
Use `mkdir` function.

You can check if directory already exists with `-d $dir` (see `perldoc -f -X`).